# Selenium scroll по дереву элементов

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

У меня есть веб элемент дерово, элементы которого появляются по мере скролинка по нему.

как в WebDriver сделать scroll по этому дереву?

для выбора елемента мне нужно скролить дерево вверх и в низ для поиска узла

код веб страницы:

[image: дерево]

изобродение:

[image: вид страницы]

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь навести курсор на какой-либо элемент в списке и выполнить нажатие клавиши "стрелочка вниз":

```
actions.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```

И сделать ожидание элемента  цикле:

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {

            if(second >=60 || getField(fieldName).isEnabled()){
                break;
            }
           actions.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
           try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```